# Eclipse Forms - ExpandableComposite

Tags: eclipse, forms, rcp

I have the following code:

```
        ExpandableComposite composite = toolkit.createExpandableComposite(sectionClient, 
            ExpandableComposite.CLIENT_INDENT | ExpandableComposite.TREE_NODE |
            ExpandableComposite.EXPANDED | SWT.FILL);
        composite.setText("Task Updates...");

        HyperlinkGroup group = new HyperlinkGroup(composite.getDisplay());

        Integer numTasks = acts.get(i).getTaskUpdates().size();
        for(int j = 0; j < numTasks; j++) {
            ImageHyperlink imageLink = toolkit.createImageHyperlink(composite, SWT.NONE);
            imageLink.setText("Task update link");
            imageLink.setImage(Activator.getImageDescriptor("icons/task.ico").createImage());
            imageLink.addHyperlinkListener(new HyperlinkAdapter() {
                public void linkActivated(HyperlinkEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("Image link activated.");
                }
            });
            group.add(imageLink);
            composite.setClient(imageLink);

        }
```

When I use the ExpandableComposite with just a single element, like Label or Hyperlink, it works just fine. However, when I try to display several elements in the ExpandableComposite, it doesn't show anything, and it doesn't throw any exception. I've tried going through the tutorial at http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Forms/article.html, but nothing seems to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ExpandableComposite` can have only one client. That's why your code does not work with multiple hyperlinks.

If you want to place more than one `ImageHyperlink` onto your `ExpandableComposite`, you should create another `Composite` which is the client of the `ExpandableComposite`, and place the hyperlinks on this composite.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Tillmann. I managed to implement it. I was using a loop, and had to declare the `Composite` outside the loop for it to work.